# Are the unicorns' outfits referencing other film/tv franchises?

Tags: reference, regular-show

So the Regular Show episode "The Unicorns Have Got to Go" features a number of unicorns in different clothes.

[image]

It's pretty obvoius that the third unicorn from the left is wearing an outfit referencing Alex DeLarge from A Clockwork Orange.

[image]

However, I can't quite make out if any of the other unicorns are wearing outfits referencing other movies and/or TV shows. Given that Regular Show is chock full of referential humor, I wouldn't put it beyond reason to suspect that these other outfits might also be referential.

Answer (score 4):

The only one I can back up with a link and image is the 5th unicorn, who looks a lot like [Gallagher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallagher_%28comedian%29) and is also mentioned on the [Regular Show wiki for The Unicorns](http://regularshow.wikia.com/wiki/Unicorns#Appearance):

[image: Gallagher and 5th Unicorn]

The same article also mentions that the 2nd unicorn is [credited as Billy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1737539/fullcredits) and his blonde spiked hair is exaggerated but he does basically resemble [Billy Idol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Idol):

[image: Billy Idol and 2nd Unicorn]

The only other one that stood out to me is the 1st unicorn's shirt and hair resemble [Sid from Toy Story](http://pixar.wikia.com/Sid_Phillips), though I'm not sure about it:

[image: Sid & 1st Unicorn]

I'm inclined to think the rest are probably just generic "punk" looks (except maybe the one in underwear, though I can't think of any young characters that do that), unless it's a portmanteau of Walter White and Jesse Pinkman from Breaking Bad.

Comment: Didn't Billy Idol wear a mesh shirt in one of his videos?  My memory is shot, but I could swear he did, which would make the Billy Idol unicorn even more logical.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I'm sure he did but I couldn't find any screenshots, searching for t-shirts just gets you a million stores which sell billy idol shirts.

Comment: @JohnnyBones maybe that was Miley Cyrus? :P Billy Idol was mostly shirtless or wearing an open vest https://img2.timeinc.net/people/i/2013/redcarpet/met-gala/reminds-us/miley-cyrus-660.jpg